# magento upload animated gif for products and page images not working

Tags: magento

I found this code on internet and everything works fine but I dont want to resize gif images because when I resize animated gif files, destroying animation. Or if it is easy to make resize animated gif images without losing animation ,,,

Comment: plz help me when i  upload gif image from magento admin its not working on frontend

Comment: after applying suppe 10570 patch gif not working in magento any one help me